# iron-media-query not hiding local DOM elements if initially loaded in smaller viewport

Tags: media-queries, polymer-1.0

Has anyone run into issues where iron-media-query doesn't seem to be setting the query-matches bound property on initial loading of the site?  In other words, if the site is initially loaded in a smaller viewport (such as on mobile or in desktop in smaller window), various local DOM elements are not being hidden using `hidden$="{{_smallScreen}}"`

However, if the site is initially loaded in a larger viewport and then subsequently reduced in size, the iron-media-query hides the local DOM elements appropriately.

Comment: Looks like this has been reported as a potential issue in GitHub repository for iron-media-query:  https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-media-query/issues/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been reported as a potential iron-media-query bug in GitHub repository here:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-media-query/issues/15

Still, does anyone have any suggestions to get around this problem?

**UPDATE:**

This actually ended up being a bug with iron-list.  Here is the actual root cause issue on github:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/107